# Does an equivalent method/technique to jQuery masonry exist in Xaml?

Tags: c#, jquery, xaml

I am relatively new to Xaml and I'm finding I both love and hate it.  It can do so much, but it is also sometimes remarkably difficult to do things that should be simple.  Granted, that might also be related to a lack of experience. :)

Anyway, before I try to go write something to do it, I am trying to figure out if there is a proven method for arranging displayed objects/tiles/div areas based on the screen/window size in Xaml.

Not necc a here's my code question, so much as a can someone point me in the right direction.

bonus: I'd also like to achieve something akin to infinite scroll if that can be done.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried WrapPanel, or VariableSizedWrapGrid for a couple examples?

Comment: Oh man, you sent me spiraling on a WPF/XAML rabbit hole, awesome and thank you that WrapPanel got me going in the right direction just the nudge I needed :)

Comment: Oh cool, glad you got your remedy. Guess I'll go ahead and make it an answer so I can mooch the points? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) seems like a good option for you. I might also suggest for a neat little trick to use for some added effect you might apply [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723946%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to your WrapPanel to give it a little simple to do pizazz on transitions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can I add, that there is an open-source [WPF-Masonry library](https://github.com/Lizzaran/WPF-Masonry%20WPF-Masonry%20library)?

Also, there is a related question, which have example of this library usage [Fluid layout wrap panel / VariableSizedWrapGrid in desktop applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590930/fluid-layout-wrap-panel-variablesizedwrapgrid-in-desktop-applications%20Fluid%20layout%20wrap%20panel%20/%20VariableSizedWrapGrid%20in%20desktop%20applications?)