# Fluid layout wrap panel / VariableSizedWrapGrid in desktop applications?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, variablesizedwrapgrid

Is it possible to use the [VariableSizedWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227651.aspx) control in desktop apps (i.e. Windows 7 WPF applications)?  Presently this control only seems available in WinRT, Windows 8, Windows Phone, etc.  If it's possible, how?  Otherwise, what option would I have to get the same sort of functionality?

For those who aren't familiar with the concept, it would be similar to a WrapPanel, however elements would fill open spaces in the panel rather than spill over onto the next row, like so (see also [Masonry for jQuery](http://masonry.desandro.com/)):

[image: variablesizedwrapgrid]

Comment: I noticed you've been doing a large number of tag wiki edits -- I'd like to point out that if you copy-and-paste entire text verbatim into tag wikis, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/3241880?&_suid=138306916383304554409544383326), please [attribute the source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki) at the end of the wiki, otherwise you are committing plagiarism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up utilizing Lizzaran's [WPF-Masonry library](https://github.com/Lizzaran/WPF-Masonry), which is pretty nice.  It didn't come with any dependency properties for proper binding, but it wouldn't be difficult to add them.  I'm also using MahApps' [latest Metro library](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) (different than the one that's available through nuget) for their tile control, but that's not necessary.

Here's what it ended up looking like:

[image: tiles screenshot]

Here is the brunt of the code:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TileExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Masonry="clr-namespace:MasonryLibrary;assembly=MasonryLibrary"
        Title="Tiles"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Height="400"
        Width="600">
  <Grid>
    <Masonry:Masonry x:Name="ui_masonry"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Animation="False">
    </Masonry:Masonry>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var tile = new Tile();
    tile.Header = i.ToString();
    ui_masonry.Add(tile);
  }
}
```

Tile.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TileExample.Tile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Width="140"
             Height="140"
             Name="ui_ctrl"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro.Resources;component/Icons.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatSlider.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Effects/Animations.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Controls:Tile Title="Not Used"
                 x:Name="ui_tile"
                 Click="Tile_Click">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ui_tile_content">
    </ItemsControl>
  </Controls:Tile>
</UserControl>
```

Tile.xaml.cs:

```
  public partial class Tile : UserControl {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header",
                                                                                       typeof(string),
                                                                                       typeof(Tile));
    public Tile() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Tile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      //Your animation code here...
      //I utilized some animations from my own library for this that simply
      //expands the tile to twice its width and height
    }

    public string Header {
      get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
      set {
        SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        ui_tile.Title = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

I added some animations to my tiles so that they expand when a user clicks on them.  The Masonry library performs pretty well with an occasional glitch, but I'm pretty happy with how it turned out.  I eventually added some UI logic to only allow for one tile to be expanded at time.

Comment: @Mark - I think the algorithm tries to find space for 7, can't find space next to 6, finds the next available location, then iterates through the remaining tiles trying to find space for them.  If you set `Animation="True"` and `AnimationSpeed="1"` on the Masonry control, it's more clear how the tiles get situated (and maybe makes a little more sense to the user when interaction occurs).

Comment: Ah...that makes sense. I was counting along to see how it laid them out, then I got confused when it jumped to 8. Didn't consider that it wouldn't fit!

Comment: Is it possible to the dynamic creation of the tiles from the C# code behind to an ItemsSource that is used for MVVM projects?

Comment: @Daniel Do you have any example in which the arrangement go first vertical rather horizontal as in this example ?

Comment: I'm the author of WPF-Masonry and I have recently rewritten the complete code. It inherits from ItemControl now which enables hassle-free data binding. Also added an exmaple project, so it may be worth to check it out again! :)

Comment: @Daniel : can you share your animation stuff please ? i ant to make an expandeable layout tiles like this one https://healthcare.codeplex.com

Comment: @user2475096 I am so sorry -- I really wish I did, but it has been some years since I worked at the place where I developed those libraries. However -- really they were not difficult to develop.  Just take a look at some animations for changing width and height, and be sure to include the "speed up" and "slow down" portions of the animations so they feel organic.  You'll find these animations are quick to develop.  Best of luck!

Comment: It hurt my head that he's expecting Framework elements in the ItemsSource. 
I bound my data and used ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(child) instead.