# Multi height cell in a GridView - XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I've made a dynamic GridView that take some information from a DataBase.

Every GridViewCell is made of a another Grid so every Cell has a different number of row inside...

My problem is that if I have a cell with lots of rows the table looks weird...

Here's how I'd like to create my GridView:

```
┌─────┬────┬────┐
│     │    │    │
│     ├────┤    │
├─────┤    │    │
│     │    ├────┤
│     ├────┤    │
└─────┴────┴────┘
```

I hope that anyone can help me :D

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

The Grid:

```
<Grid>
   <GridView
         x:Name="listaSpecifiche" SelectionMode="None"
         IsSwipeEnabled="false" Height="Auto"
         IsItemClickEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sorgenteListaSpecifiche}}"
         IsHitTestVisible="False" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource specificaTemplate}">
      <GridView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemsPanel>
      <GridView.GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource gruppoSpecificaTemplate}">
               <GroupStyle.Panel>
                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                       <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,20,0" Visibility="Visible"/>
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
           </GroupStyle>
       </GridView.GroupStyle>
       <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-9,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
           </Style>
       </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
  </GridView>
</Grid>
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="specificaTemplate">
     <Grid Margin="0">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="7,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Descrizione}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Valore}"/>
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate x:Key="gruppoSpecificaTemplate">
     <Grid Margin="5,0,0,5">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="650"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <StackPanel Background="#BB000795" Height="30" Grid.Row="0">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="7,-10,0,0" />
         </StackPanel>

     </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

I've tryed to change the creation of the group of GridView, now I'm not using a grouped GridView and it's just a ListView of GridView, the problem persist, I think it's because the

```
 <WrapGrid Orientation='Vertical' />
```

I've tryed to use a *StackPanel* or a *VirtualisingStackPanel* and now there's only one column (so lots of Grids now are over the margin).

Is there a way to create 1 ore more column when there's some overflow in a *StackPanel* ?

Comment: What does "werid" mean? Can you show us your current code and what it does?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong control for the job. Maybe you need a set of StackPanels or something else

Comment: I've added my code, I'm using a GridView because I need to use the GroupStyle for make different tables from a single source

Comment: I mean weird cells because every cell has the height of the one of its left so if the first one has like 10 rows inside and the second has just 1 it has 9 rows empty

Comment: You can change your grid with a combination of grid and StackPanels or use rowSpan values to get that design. As @GlenThomas said you're using the wrong control for the job.

Comment: I'm not very good with XAML, can you please make an example of code?

Comment: I've edited the code but the problem persist, I've added an EDIT about my current situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

After hours... and hours... and hours of web searching I've discovered a function class that permit to use the WrapPanel inside a Windows Store Application.

The link to my savior: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463860/WinRT-Custom-WrapPanel

Thanks anyone :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't easily get this layout if you don't have constant amount of child controls, which you can arrange manually.
There are implemented custom panels, which you may try to look up by word "masonry"

Here are relevant links:

- [Fluid layout wrap panel / VariableSizedWrapGrid in desktop applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590930/fluid-layout-wrap-panel-variablesizedwrapgrid-in-desktop-applications)
- [jQuery Masonry layout for WPF?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/60e1bc43-7b68-4d14-9587-ddfb740b1a5d/jquery-masonry-layout-for-wpf)
- [Does an equivalent method/technique to jQuery masonry exist in Xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418244/does-an-equivalent-method-technique-to-jquery-masonry-exist-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achieve that look - with StackPanels that contain further StackPanels. There are other ways that you could do this but you'll be subject to flow and window size - I presume you want your positioning fairly static.

If you have a grid with a single row and three columns, then add stackpanels to specific columns

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Height="200" />
        <StackPanel />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel Height="100" />
        <StackPanel Height="200" />
        <StackPanel Height="100" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2">
        <StackPanel Height="250" />
        <StackPanel Height="150" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

this approach will let the panels in each column grow down unconstrained. I've assigned arbitrary heights to them so you can see their boundaries in the designer.

If you want to constrain them then you need to use grid cells and be creative with your use of rows and row heights for each cell, and put the panels inside specific cells:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't have a static number of grids or rows, they come from a db. When I'll set the item source of my listview it's a List<T> of a class that has a String and a List<T> of another class.